# How to set the text/value/content of an `Entry` widget using a button in tkinter

Tags: python, events, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am trying to set the text of an `Entry` widget using a button in a GUI using the `tkinter` module.

This GUI is to help me classify thousands of words into five categories. Each of the categories has a button. I was hoping that using a button would significantly speed me up and I want to double check the words every time otherwise I would just use the button and have the GUI process the current word and bring the next word.

The command buttons for some reason are not behaving like I want them to. This is an example:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

win = tk.Tk()

v = tk.StringVar()
def setText(word):
    v.set(word)

a = ttk.Button(win, text="plant", command=setText("plant"))
a.pack()
b = ttk.Button(win, text="animal", command=setText("animal"))
b.pack()
c = ttk.Entry(win, textvariable=v)
c.pack()
win.mainloop()
```

So far, when I am able to compile, the click does nothing.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

You might want to use [`insert`](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111190045id_/https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm#Tkinter.Entry.insert-method) method. [You can find the documentation for the Tkinter Entry Widget here.](https://web.archive.org/web/20201105231837id_/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm)

This script inserts a text into `Entry`. The inserted text can be changed in `command` parameter of the Button.

```
from tkinter import *

def set_text(text):
    e.delete(0,END)
    e.insert(0,text)
    return

win = Tk()

e = Entry(win,width=10)
e.pack()

b1 = Button(win,text="animal",command=lambda:set_text("animal"))
b1.pack()

b2 = Button(win,text="plant",command=lambda:set_text("plant"))
b2.pack()

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Just want to say to newcomers, that you may have `import tkinter as tk`, so, the line with `e.delete(0,END)` becomes `e.delete(0,tk.END)`.

Comment: @m3nda: True, by even when using `import tkinter as tk`, it's still often convenient to follow it with a `from tkinter.constants import *` to avoid having the prefix the many constants in the module defines with `tk.` — although you can also just use a literal string instead which doesn't require importing anything. i.e. `e.delete(0,'end')` or `e.delete(0,'END')`.

Answer (score 39):

If you use a "text variable" `tk.StringVar()`, you can just `set()` that.

No need to use the Entry delete and insert.  Moreover, those functions don't work when the Entry is disabled or readonly!  The text variable method, however, does work under those conditions as well.

```
import Tkinter as tk

...

entry_text = tk.StringVar()
entry = tk.Entry( master, textvariable=entry_text )
entry_text.set( "Hello World" )
```

Comment: But if I already have an `Entry` object, how do I get its `StringVar` object?

Comment: I guess you don't want to keep your `StringVar` in scope?  I can see that... Well, check out this SO thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221908/is-it-possible-to-get-widget-settings-in-tkinter That shows how to get the attributes of a Tk Widget through a couple of means.  I didn't test it, but you should be able to access the `textvariable` that way.

Comment: BuvinJ: If you have to first call `cget()` to get the `StringVar` associated with the `Entry` widget, it kind of defeats the purpose of using one in this scenario IMO. Also, when you're responding to someone else's comment, you should put @ + their username in it (which you didn't do for @Madlozoz's). Regardless, I think this is a good answer.

Answer (score 24):

You can choose between the following two methods to set the text of an `Entry` widget. For the examples, assume imported library `import tkinter as tk` and root window `root = tk.Tk()`.

---

- **Method A: Use `delete` and `insert`**

  Widget `Entry` provides methods `delete` and `insert` which can be used to set its text to a new value. First, you'll have to remove any former, old text from `Entry` with `delete` which needs the positions where to start and end the deletion. Since we want to remove the full old text, we start at `0` and end at wherever the end currently is. We can access that value via `END`. Afterwards the `Entry` is empty and we can insert `new_text` at position `0`.

  ```
  entry = tk.Entry(root)
  new_text = "Example text"
  entry.delete(0, tk.END)
  entry.insert(0, new_text)
  ```

---

- **Method B: Use `StringVar`**

  You have to create a new `StringVar` object called `entry_text` in the example. Also, your `Entry` widget has to be created with keyword argument `textvariable`. Afterwards, every time you change `entry_text` with `set`, the text will automatically show up in the `Entry` widget.

  ```
  entry_text = tk.StringVar()
  entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=entry_text)
  new_text = "Example text"
  entry_text.set(new_text)
  ```

---

- **Complete working example which contains both methods to set the text via `Button`:**

  This window

  [image: screenshot]

  is generated by the following complete working example:

  ```
  import tkinter as tk

  def button_1_click():
      # define new text (you can modify this to your needs!)
      new_text = "Button 1 clicked!"
      # delete content from position 0 to end
      entry.delete(0, tk.END)
      # insert new_text at position 0
      entry.insert(0, new_text)

  def button_2_click():
      # define new text (you can modify this to your needs!)
      new_text = "Button 2 clicked!"
      # set connected text variable to new_text
      entry_text.set(new_text)

  root = tk.Tk()

  entry_text = tk.StringVar()
  entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=entry_text)

  button_1 = tk.Button(root, text="Button 1", command=button_1_click)
  button_2 = tk.Button(root, text="Button 2", command=button_2_click)

  entry.pack(side=tk.TOP)
  button_1.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
  button_2.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

  root.mainloop()
  ```

Comment: Can you state the advantages and disadvantages of each method? Why would one choose one over the other?

Comment: What does this add to the conversation other than more examples?  You've simply recycled the top two answers, posted years prior to this.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that when you do this:

```
a = Button(win, text="plant", command=setText("plant"))
```

it tries to evaluate what to set for the command.  So when instantiating the `Button` object, it actually calls `setText("plant")`.  This is wrong, because you don't want to call the setText method yet.  Then it takes the return value of this call (which is `None`), and sets that to the command of the button.  That's why clicking the button does nothing, because there is no command set for it.

If you do as Milan Skála suggested and use a lambda expression instead, then your code will work (assuming you fix the indentation and the parentheses).

Instead of `command=setText("plant")`, which actually *calls* the function, you can set `command=lambda:setText("plant")` which specifies something which will call the function later, when you want to call it.

If you don't like lambdas, another (slightly more cumbersome) way would be to define a pair of functions to do what you want:

```
def set_to_plant():
    set_text("plant")
def set_to_animal():
    set_text("animal")
```

and then you can use `command=set_to_plant` and `command=set_to_animal` - these will evaluate to the corresponding functions, but are definitely *not* the same as `command=set_to_plant()` which would of course evaluate to `None` again.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to inherit a new class,`EntryWithSet`, and defining `set` method that makes use of [`delete`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm#Tkinter.Entry.delete-method) and [`insert`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm#Tkinter.Entry.insert-method) methods of the [`Entry`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm) class objects:

```
try:                        # In order to be able to import tkinter for
    import tkinter as tk    # either in python 2 or in python 3
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk


class EntryWithSet(tk.Entry):
    """
    A subclass to Entry that has a set method for setting its text to
    a given string, much like a Variable class.
    """

    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Entry.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)


    def set(self, text_string):
        """
        Sets the object's text to text_string.
        """

        self.delete('0', 'end')
        self.insert('0', text_string)


def on_button_click():
    import random, string
    rand_str = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for _ in range(19))
    entry.set(rand_str)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    entry = EntryWithSet(root)
    entry.pack()
    tk.Button(root, text="Set", command=on_button_click).pack()
    tk.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
e= StringVar()
def fileDialog():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",title = "Select A 
    File",filetype = (("jpeg","*.jpg"),("png","*.png"),("All Files","*.*")))
    e.set(filename)
la = Entry(self,textvariable = e,width = 30).place(x=230,y=330)
butt=Button(self,text="Browse",width=7,command=fileDialog).place(x=430,y=328)
```

Comment: If You want to put the Location Of a Image in Entry Widget