# How to detect a selected text using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, operating-system, copy-paste

I'm looking for a way to copy a selected text in a `tkinter.scrolledtext` and paste it automatically in an `Entry`.

Means, Every time a user selects a text it will be added to the `tkinter Entry` automatically.

Any suggestions? specially on how to get the selected text.

Comment: I think this is helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16373887/how-to-set-the-text-value-content-of-an-entry-widget-using-a-button-in-tkinter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `selection` event generated from `text` widget to add to your `entry` widget.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import scrolledtext as tkst

root = tk.Tk()

txt = tkst.ScrolledText(root)
txt.insert(tk.END, "This is a test phrase")
txt.pack()

entry = tk.Entry(root)
entry.pack()

def select_event(event):
    try:
        entry.delete(0, tk.END)
        entry.insert(0, txt.get(tk.SEL_FIRST, tk.SEL_LAST))
    except tk.TclError:
        pass

txt.bind("<<Selection>>", select_event)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I was looking exactly for this line:
`txt.bind("<<Selection>>", select_event)`

Thank you!