# Append string to StringVar instance through button press (tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a basic calculator in Tkinter and I'm having trouble with the text field and the number buttons. I'd like the button presses to show up in the `Entry()` window, but I don't know how to deal with a `StringVar` instance. It keeps telling me, that `StringVar` has no `.extend()` Attribute, even though it was used in a different post (older version maybe?). Right now all my button can do is `.set()` the entry to '0' and nothing else.

Basically, I'd like the button presses to dynamically update my StringVar, as in extend the string from left to right. Optimally, I could use both the button as well as direct text input to update the `StringVar` (Is that what trace is for?). Is `StringVar` even the correct class for that? I'm very new to GUI programming so I don't know what to use.

```py
import tkinter as tk

def N0(text):

    text.set('0')

root = tk.Tk()
formula = tk.StringVar()

Num_bw = 0.08
Num_bh = 0.15

Num_bx = 0.01
Num_by = 0.01

Num_bx0 = 0
Num_by0 = 0

Num_bw_tol = 0.004
Num_bh_tol = 0.01

width, height = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()
width  *= 0.5
height *= 0.5
r = width/height

root.geometry('%dx%d+0+0'%(width,height))

canvas = tk.Canvas(root,height=height,width=width,bg='#80dfff')
canvas.pack()

frame1 = tk.Frame(canvas,bg='#f2f2f2')                  
frame2 = tk.Frame(canvas,bg='#f2f2f2')

frame1.place(relx=0.03,rely=0.05,relwidth=0.94,relheight=0.2)
frame2.place(relx=0.07,rely=0.27,relwidth=0.86,relheight=0.68)                  

TextField = tk.Entry(frame1,bg='white',
                     textvariable=formula,
                     font=("Comic Sans MS", 15))

TextField.place(relx=0.01,rely=0.05,relwidth=0.98,relheight=0.9)

Num_0 = tk.Button(frame2,text='0',bg='#e6ffff',command=lambda:N0(formula))

Num_0.place(relx=Num_bw_tol*1 + Num_bx0 + Num_bw*1,
            rely=Num_bh_tol*5 + Num_by0 + Num_bh*5,
            relwidth=Num_bw,relheight=Num_bh)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: _"even though it was used in a different post "_. Sounds interesting. Can you provide a link to that post?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16373887/how-to-set-the-text-value-content-of-an-entry-widget-using-a-button-in-tkinter
Aaaaaand I need glasses. It's appied to Entry...

Comment: @J.Doe Read about [The Variable Classes (StringVar)](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a Tkinter guru myself, but maybe you can create a function that will update the "calculator screen" on each button press like this

```
def updateButton(num, text):
    text.set(text.get() + str(num))
```

And call the function as the onclick for each of the calculator buttons, just like you did for the N0 function

Comment: Big McThankies from McSpankies.