# in tkinter , how should I command a button to enter its text in the selected entry

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

In tkinter, how should I command a button to enter its text in the selected entry

```
import tkinter as tk
tk.Entry(master, width=20,columnspan=2).grid(row=0,column=0)
tk.Button(master,command=?)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set the text/value/content of an \`Entry\` widget using a button in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16373887/how-to-set-the-text-value-content-of-an-entry-widget-using-a-button-in-tkinter)

Comment: no , two many entries one button

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do actually.

Comment: man , I have many entries and one button , how could I insert button's command or text in the selected entry

Answer (score 0):

My answer is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16374273/11573842)

```py
import tkinter as tk

entry = tk.Entry(master, width=20,columnspan=2)
entry.grid(row=0,column=0)

def set_text(text):
    entry.delete(0,tk.END) # clear any previously entered text
    entry.insert(0,text) #insert new text
    return

text = 'hello' # text of button
tk.Button(master,text = text,command=lambda:set_text(text))
```