# How to make an if statement using widget option values as conditions?

Tags: python, if-statement, tkinter, conditional-statements

Let's say i have a this button:

```
tl.config(bd=0 ,image=photo1 ,width="100",height="100",command=lambda: functionPlus(tl))
```

The function is :

```
def functionPlus(button):

   global turn

   if (turn==1 or turn==3 or turn==5 or turn==7 or turn==9):
       button.config(image=photo2,width="100",height="100")
       turn +=1

   elif (turn==2 or turn==4 or turn==6 or turn==8) :
       button.config(image=photo3,width="100",height="100")
       turn+=1
```

I would like to add an 'if' in the function, that would have as condition the image of the button. For exemple :

```
if button.config(image=photo2 == True) :
   anotherFunction()
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, **never** use the expression pattern `something=something else == True`!

Second, take a look at [this **related** (but not duplicate) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221908/is-it-possible-to-get-widget-settings-in-tkinter).

As you can see there, the [cget](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) method will *return the current value for an option*.  As [this manual page mentions](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html), `cget` is analogous to `widget["option"]`.

---

**So,** to answer your question directly, the `if` condition you need would be along the lines of:

```
if button['image']==photo2:
   anotherFunction()
```

Comment: Okay ! Thank you for your solution and your advice, the code is working now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new here and couldn't comment. I hope I'm not flaunting SO policy by resorting to answering instead.

@Tersosauros

> "First, never use the expression pattern something=something else ==
>   True!"

Where do you see this pattern and why should it be avoided? What could replace it? (I know you're a tersosaurus but "never use X" just seems TOO terse and uninformative).

@Arwan Credoz I know you got your answer but... If you simply want to check whether the value of "turn" is a an even/odd number and is within a given range, use a bounds check followed by modulus instead (maybe this is what @Tersosauros was hinting at?). 
Also, the value of "turn" will always be incremented if it's within range(0,10) so there's no need to write "turn+=1" twice. If I've understood your intentions correctly, you could probably rewrite "functionPlus" to something like this and add Tersosaurus' addition where appropriate:

```
def functionPlus(button):
    global turn
    if 0 < turn < 10:
        if turn % 2 == 0:
            button.config(image=photo3,width="100",height="100")
        else:
            button.config(image=photo2,width="100",height="100")
        turn += 1
```

Comment: Hah, interesting!  I didn't even read much of that function...  but you're absolutely right!  Those if conditions *in* `functionPlus` could just use modulus.
My focus had been on the next if statement (in the separate code block), which *wasn't working* - so I fixed it.

Comment: As for your question regarding the [a=b == True](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_%28computer_science%29#Assignment_versus_equality) pattern, this would *best be asked in a **separate** question* (of your own, so you can earn some reputation to get past that comment-block),  but essentially this relates to the [confusion of the equality and assignment operators](http://www.google.com/search?q=assignment+equality+confusion).

Comment: @Tersosauros Yeah, you answered the actual question - I just refactored a bit (thus, my answer should've been a comment, I guess). Anyway, I overlooked the last line (image=photo2 == True) so I didn't understand why you mentioned the misuse of assignment/equality operators in the first place. My bad.