# How to get current spinbox 'from' and 'to' values

Tags: python, tkinter, spinbox

How to get the values of spinbox from and to in a function?

```
sbDays=tk.Spinbox(frame,from_=0,to=366)
sbDays.place(relx=initialX,rely=yDistance)
sbDays.configure(validate='all',validatecommand=(windows.register(validate),'%P'))

def validate(userInput): 
    if userInput=="":
        return True

    try:
        val=int(float(userInput))
    except ValueError:
        return False
    return val>=0 and val<=366
```

Instead of `return val>=0 and val<=366`. I need this:

```
minVal=spinbox 'from' value of '0'
maxVal=spinbox 'to' value of '366'

return val>=minVal and val<=maxVal
```

In C#, something like this:

```
minVal=this.From()
maxVal=this.To()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `cget` method to get attributes from a widget.
In this case, you need `minVal = sbDays.cget("from")` and `maxVal = sbDays.cget("to")`

**Edit - For multiple spinboxes**
To use this with multiple spinboxes, change the `validatecommand` to
 `validatecommand=(windows.register(validate),'%P', '%W')`
and change `validate(userInput)` to `validate(userInput, widget)`. Then replace `sbDays` in my answer with `windows.nametowidget(widget)` and it should work.

The `%W` in the `validatecommand` gives the name of the widget (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4140988/7519434)), which is then used to get the widget with `nametowidget` (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8895847/7519434)).

Comment: Is there a reason why `cget` is better than `config` or is it just a preference? I usually use `config` to set and get values from tkinter widgets.

Comment: @TheLizzard I forgot to mention that I have several spinbox that is calling from the function.

Comment: @TheLizzard From the looks of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3222000), it seems like they're pretty much the same

Comment: @Vincent I've updated my answer to work with multiple spinboxes

Comment: It worked. I'm using C# for 8years now and today marks my 3rd day of using Python. It seems the syntax and calling the functions are way too different.

Comment: Glad that helped. Tkinter does have some odd syntax sometimes.

Comment: @TheLizzard: `config` will return a list of values. `cget` returns exactly one value, making it more convenient if you're only interested in the currently configured value.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `.config` method like this:
`sbDays.config("from")` and `sbDays.config("to")`. It returns something like `('from', 'from', 'From', 0, 0.0)` or `('to', 'to', 'To', 0, 366.0)`. Note the last value is the one we need so using `sbDays.config(...)[-1]` should give the desired result.

Comment: Note that `.config("from")` will return a tuple with the last item as the value, whereas `.cget("from")` gets the value directly.

Comment: @acw1668 thx for noting that I will change my answer.